# many boxes(div elements), has a blank spaces between them

Tags: html, css

I have many boxes(`div`) are different sizes.
The following is screenshot about the problem:
[image]

**My code:**

**HTML**

```
<div id="categories_container">
    <div class="main_category">
        <div class="categories_title"><a href="#"> <img src="template/images/image.png" alt="" /><h2> Title </h2></a>

            <div style="clear:both;"></div>
        </div>
        <ul>
            <li> <a href="#" title=""> item </a> 
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div#center_container {}
div#categories_container {width:65%; margin:5px; float:left;}
div.main_category {width:197px; float:right; margin:0 10px 10px 0;}
div.categories_title img {float:right; margin-left:5px}
div.categories_title h2{float:right; font-size:20px;}
div.main_category ul {list-style-type:none; margin:0; padding:0}
div.main_category ul li {margin: 0 0 .2em 0;}
div.main_category ul li a{color:#6E6B64; font:normal 18px tahoma; display:block; background-color:#f4f4f4; padding: .2em .3em;}
div.main_category ul li a:hover {color:#F37020; background-color:#e7e7e7;}
```

I want no blank space between every box, no matter what the size of each box.

Comment: please give jsfiddle to it

Comment: it will be better to share actual url.

Comment: There is a way to solve this problem, but I don't remember, we will apply `position: relative` on the parent and `position: absolute` on the children.

Comment: I hope your solution will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to remove unwanted spaces, you can create three container and place your categories

**HTML**

```
<div id="categories_container">
    <div class="col col1">
      <div class="category">cat</div>
      <div class="category">cat</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col col2">
      <div class="category">cat</div>
      <div class="category">cat</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col col3">
      <div class="category">cat</div>
      <div class="category">cat</div>
    </div>   
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.col {
   width: 33%;
   float: left;
}

#categories_container {
   overflow: hidden;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sK743/)

Comment: Thanks, but you have used in the inner `2 div`, and I want one div to be the title of box, then the next element will be a list `ex: ul li`.

Comment: Exactly yes, that is what I want. I will study your code soon, and if it is works fine, I will give you the best answer. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks, but see the demo after add more blocks [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/sK743/4/)

Comment: @LionKing do not add new `col` to your html, add your categories to these three columns

Comment: Yes, now I'm understood your idea, there are three block, each one as a parent, then each parent have blocks as its children. is that correct ?

Comment: Yes, these tree columns are parents, and your categories are children of these parents @LionKing

Comment: create three variable `$col1` `$col2` `$col3`, and category tags to these variables and finally print each of these in columns

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
div.main_category {width:197px; float:right; margin:0 10px 10px 0;}
```

to

```
div.main_category {width:197px; float:right; margin:0 10px 0 0;}
```

margin: TOP RIGHT BOTTOM LEFT

Comment: Unfortunate, the problem still exists.

Comment: Can you please provide the full html code for all the boxes?

Answer (score 0):

The `#categories_container` or another class wrapping the top row is setting a defined height for the row. Did you check that?

Comment: Yes, there is another parent div `<div id="center_container">`, but I do not apply any css code on that element.